# using .NetFramwork library in .netcore

Tags: .net-core

I want to use .NetFramwork Library in my .NetCore application.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/

Is there any way to port this application to .NetCore, even though SignalR is available to .NetCore but it does not have all the features as in Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core

Comment: That's the *wrong* package. The correct one is Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core

Answer (score 0):

**.NET Core Apps** can use libs: **.NETCoreApp** or **.NETStandard**. It cannot use **.NETFramework**.

You can try to port lib from **.NETFramework** to **.NETCore**:

References: [Microsoft Documents - Port your code from .NET Framework to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)

> Overview of the porting process This is the process we recommend you
>   take when porting your project to .NET Core. Each step of the process
>   is covered in more detail in further articles.
>
> Identify and account for your third-party dependencies.
>
> This step involves understanding what your third-party dependencies
>   are, how you depend on them, how to check if they also run on .NET
>   Core, and steps you can take if they don't. It also covers how you can
>   migrate your dependencies over to the PackageReference format that is
>   used in .NET Core.
>
> Retarget all projects you wish to port to target the .NET Framework
>   4.7.2 or higher.
>
> This step ensures that you can use API alternatives for .NET
>   Framework-specific targets when .NET Core doesn't support a particular
>   API.
>
> Use the .NET Portability Analyzer to analyze your assemblies and
>   develop a plan to port based on its results.
>
> The API Portability Analyzer tool analyzes your compiled assemblies
>   and generates a report that shows a high-level portability summary and
>   a breakdown of each API you're using that isn't available on .NET
>   Core. You can use this report alongside an analysis of your codebase
>   to develop a plan for how you'll port your code over.
>
> Port your tests code.
>
> Because porting to .NET Core is such a significant change to your
>   codebase, it's highly recommended to get your tests ported, so that
>   you can run tests as you port your code over. MSTest, xUnit, and NUnit
>   all support .NET Core.
>
> Execute your plan for porting!
>
> The following list shows tools you might find helpful to use during
>   the porting process:
>
> .NET Portability Analyzer - command line tool or Visual Studio
>   Extension, a toolchain that can generate a report of how portable your
>   code is between .NET Framework and .NET Core, with an
>   assembly-by-assembly breakdown of issues. For more information, see
>   .NET Portability Analyzer. .NET API analyzer - A Roslyn analyzer that
>   discovers potential compatibility risks for C# APIs on different
>   platforms and detects calls to deprecated APIs. For more information,
>   see .NET API analyzer. Reverse Package Search - A useful web service
>   that allows you to search for a type and find packages containing that
>   type.

[Soure code (Github) - Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core)

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to use the wrong package. You should add [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/) instead. ASP.NET Core SignalR isn't just the Core version of SignalR, it's a complete rewrite